# how use gem package to run command line in ruby

Tags: ruby, rubygems

I just wondering can we turn a command line tool that written in ruby to a gem file ? if yes how we can run that gem ?
think I have a ruby file which print a text very simple app 
now I want to package it to a gem file 
then I need to run that gem 
Is this doable or not ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is perfectly possible. RubyGem has a [guide](http://guides.rubygems.org/make-your-own-gem/) on this. Basically you'll need to:

Apart the gem structure, you'll want to see [how to add an executable](http://guides.rubygems.org/make-your-own-gem/#adding-an-executable) to it by creating a file in the bin folder with something like:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

require 'yourmainfile'
# call your code here
```